# column_stack returns non cotiguous array

Tags: pandas, numpy, contiguous

I am having a problem in my code with non contiguous arrays.
In particular I get the following warning message:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\shape.py:247: RuntimeWarning: Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input array without copying.
  warn(RuntimeWarning("Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input "
```

I am using [np.column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])

y = np.array([5,6,7,8])

stack = np.column_stack((x,y))

stack.flags.f_contiguous
Out[2]: False
```

but I get a non contiguous array

Do you know how can I get contigous array? should I use always `ascontiguousarray` after `column_stack`?

Comment: What do you mean by `contiguous` here? Do you mean something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays)? `np.column_stack` would simply stack the inputs as columns, which is what it's doing, whereas hstack would stack those horizontally in the sequence as the inputs are fed, two different operations.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/OgF4Xd) The result is contiguous for me.

Comment: please see my edit...

Comment: @Divakar Yes, sorry I thought hstack would also stack the columns... what I need is to concatenate x and y by columns

Comment: Are you getting this error with `stack` or `stack.T`.  The `stack/concatenate` variations should all produce 2d C-contiguous arrays.  `.T` will make it `F contiguous`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365826/runtimewarning-cannot-provide-views-on-a-non-contiguous-input-array-without-cop deals with the same warning - for a Fcontiguous array from MATLAB (via loadmat).  Look at the source code for `skimage\util\shape.py`.  What property is it checking?

Answer (score 0):

`np.stack([x, y])` is not contiguous.  However, `np.stack([x, y]).T` is.

```
np.stack([x, y])  # Transpose of what you want and not contiguous

array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Instead:

```
stack = np.stack([x, y]).T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [276]: xy=np.column_stack((x,y))
In [277]: np.info(xy)
class:  ndarray
shape:  (4, 2)
strides:  (8, 4)
itemsize:  4
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  False
data pointer: 0xa836ec0
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: int32
```

The `skimage` code, https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py

```
# -- build rolling window view
if not arr_in.flags.contiguous:
    warn(RuntimeWarning("Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input "
                        "array without copying."))

arr_in = np.ascontiguousarray(arr_in)
```

That test, on the `column_stack` is ok:

```
In [278]: xy.flags.contiguous
Out[278]: True
In [279]: xy.T.flags.contiguous
Out[279]: False
```

Normally constructed 2d arrays are `contiguous`.  But their transpose is `F-contiguous`.  The warning is that `np.ascontiguousarray` will produce a copy.  For very large arrays that could be a problem.

If this warning comes up often you could either suppress it, or routinely use `ascontiguousarray` before calling this function.

[RuntimeWarning: Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input array without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365826/runtimewarning-cannot-provide-views-on-a-non-contiguous-input-array-without-cop)